# Apply function to first element in a group by and then remerging

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

(sorry about the title I realise it isn't very descriptive)

Given a data set such of the following:

```
       word  entity
0   Charlie      1
1        p.      1
2    Nelson      1
3     loves   None
4      Dana      2
5        c.      2
6  anderson      2
7       and   None
8     james      3
```

I want to apply a function (e.g. get_gender()) to first element of each entity (I would imagine I groupby of some sort)

as to get something like this:

```
       word entity gender
0   Charlie      1      m
1        p.      1   None
2    Nelson      1   None
3     loves   None   None
4      Dana      2      f
5        c.      2   None
6  anderson      2   None
7       and   None   None
8     james      3      m
```

and lastly populate the missing rows of each entity to get

```
       word entity gender
0   Charlie      1      m
1        p.      1      m
2    Nelson      1      m
3     loves   None   None
4      Dana      2      f
5        c.      2      f
6  anderson      2      f
7       and   None   None
8     james      3      m
```

Here is some code for generating the above data frame

```py
import pandas as pd
df  = pd.DataFrame([("Charlie", "p.", "Nelson", "loves", "Dana", "c.", "anderson", "and", "james"), (1,1,1, None, 2,2,2, None, 3)]).transpose()
df.columns = ["word", "entity"]
```

The current 'solution' I am using is:

```
import gender_guesser.detector as gender
d = gender.Detector() 
# Detect gender in of the names in word. However this one if applied to all of the entity (including last names, furthermore one entity can be multiple genders (depending on e.g. their middle name)
df['gender'].loc[(df['entity'].isnull() == False)] = df['word'].loc[(df['entity'].isnull() == False)].apply(lambda string: d.get_gender(string.lower().capitalize()))
```

Comment: How do you know when a new entity starts? And what is the logic of your gender column?

Comment: What are you using to determine the gender?

Comment: What's the significance of the entity column? Why does it change after running it through get_gender()?

Comment: Sorry that is my mistake, entity shouldn't be changed. I should be fixed now.

Furthermore the get_gender() function currently uses the [gender guesser](https://pypi.org/project/gender-guesser/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no order after groupby, so you can't get *first* element from a group. In this case, instead you can group by *entity* and select the not None value from each group, then join with the origin DataFrame.

```
df  = pd.DataFrame([
    ("Charlie", "p.", "Nelson", "loves", "Dana", "c.", "anderson", "and", "james")
    , (1,1,1, None, 2,2,2, None, 3)
    , ('m', None, None, None, 'f', None, None, None, 'm')]).transpose()
df.columns = ["word", "entity", "gender"]

df_g = df.groupby('entity').agg({'gender': lambda x: max(filter(None, x))}).reset_index()

pd.merge(df, df_g, on='entity', suffixes=('_x', ''))[['word', 'entity', 'gender']]
```

But notice that after `groupby`, the items whose *entity* is `None` disappeared.

Comment: Thanks! This is close to an answer. I still need to apply the gender detection to the initial name in each columns, but I suspect I can create a new columns for detecting the start of an entity.